# handling input form for image upload with asp.net web api and knockout js

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

i created a single page application with knockout and asp.net web api in that may allow the user complete a form which include uploading image,

this are my codes, please you are free to correct it if requires

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public Dept Dept { get; set; }
}
```

my Seeded Data

```
context.Employees.AddOrUpdate(x => x.EmployeeId,
   new Employee()
   {
       EmployeeId =  1,
       LastName = "Carson",
       FirstName = "Alexander",
       ImagePath = "images/CarsonAlex.png",
       Address = "Brazil",
       DeptId = 2
   },
   new Employee()
   {
       EmployeeId = 2,
       LastName = "Arturo",
       FirstName = "Olivetto",
       ImagePath = "images/ArturoOliva.png",
       Address = "Brazil",
       DeptId = 1
   },
   new Employee()
   {
       EmployeeId = 3,
       LastName = "Alonso",
       FirstName = "Meredith",
       ImagePath = "images/MeredithAlonso.png",
       Address = "Brazil",
       DeptId = 3
   }
);
```

my Viewmodel class

```
public class EmployeeDetailVm
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
    public string DeptName { get; set; }
}
```

the post employee api controller

```
[ResponseType(typeof(EmployeeDetailVm))]
public IHttpActionResult PostEmployee(EmployeeDetailVm employees)
{
    var employee = new Employee
    {
        EmployeeId = employees.EmployeeId,
        LastName = employees.LastName,
        FirstName = employees.FirstName,
        ImagePath = employees.ImagePath,
        Address = employees.Address,
        DeptId = employees.DeptId
    };

    if (employees != null)
    {
        // Extract the image from the image string
        string regEx = "data:(.+);base64,(.+)";
        Match match = Regex.Match(employees.ImagePath, regEx);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            // Get the content-type of the file and the content
            string imageType = match.Groups[1].Value;
            string base64Image = match.Groups[2].Value;

            if (imageType != null && base64Image != null)
            {
                // Verify the content-type is an image
                string imageRegEx = "image/(.+)";
                match = Regex.Match(imageType, imageRegEx);
            }

            if (match.Success)
            {
                // Get the file extension from the content-type
                string fileExtension = match.Groups[1].Value;
                // Get the byte-array of the file from the base64 string

                byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);

                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images");
                string fileName = employees.FirstName + employees.LastName;

                // Generate a unique name for the file (add an index to it if it already exists)                                                        
                string targetFile = fileName + "." + fileExtension;

                int index = 0;
                while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, targetFile)))
                {
                    index++;
                    targetFile = fileName + index + "." + fileExtension;
                }

                // Write the image to the target file, and update the agent with the new image path
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, targetFile), image);
                employees.ImagePath = "images/" + targetFile;

                db.Employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();


                employees.EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId;

                return Ok(employees);

            }

        }
    }

    throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not deserialize Employee"));
}
```

here is the knockout viewmodel

```
var employeeUrl = "http://localhost:50081/api/employees";
var deptUrl = "http://localhost:50081/api/depts";

var EmployeeViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.error = ko.observable();

    self.employeeList = ko.observableArray();

    self.listDepts = ko.observableArray();

    self.newEmployee = {
        LastName: ko.observable(),
        FirstName: ko.observable(),
        ImagePath: ko.observable(),
        Address: ko.observable(),
        Dept: ko.observable()
    }


    self.ajaxHelper = function(uri, method, data) {
        self.error('');
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
        }).error(function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.error(errorThrown + ': ' + jqXhr.responseText);
        });
    },

    self.getDepts = function() {
        self.ajaxHelper(deptUrl, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.listDepts(data);
        });
    },

    self.getAllEmployee = function() {
        self.ajaxHelper(employeeUrl, 'GET').done(function(data) {
            self.employeeList(data);
        });
    },

    self.addEmployee = function (formElement) {
        var employee = {
            LastName: self.newEmployee.LastName(),
            FirstName: self.newEmployee.FirstName(),
            ImagePath: self.newEmployee.ImagePath(),
            Address: self.newEmployee.Address(),
            DeptId: self.newEmployee.Dept().DeptId
        };

        self.ajaxHelper(employeeUrl, 'POST', employee).done(function (item) {
            self.employeeList.push(item);
        });
    }

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var employeeVm = new EmployeeViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(employeeVm);
    employeeVm.getAllEmployee();
    employeeVm.getDepts();
});
```

this is my display on simple html table, this works fines

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Authors</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped ">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Photo </th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name </th>
                    <th>Dept Name </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: employeeList">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img data-bind="attr:{ src: ImagePath}" width="75" height="75"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: DeptName"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

finally this the add form ,

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: addEmployee" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dept Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control" data-bind="options:listDepts, optionsText: 'DeptName', value: newEmployee.Dept"></select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" data-bind="with: newEmployee">
            <label for="inputLastName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" data-bind="value:LastName"/>
            </div>

            <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" data-bind="value:FirstName"/>
            </div>

            <label for="inputImagePath" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Upload Photo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputImagePath" data-bind="value:ImagePath"/>
            </div>

            <label for="inputAddress" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" data-bind="value:Address"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

in my browser console i got the following error

**POST http://localhost:50081/api/employees 400 (Bad Request)**

i believe the error might have originated from the line of code

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputImagePath" data-bind="value:ImagePath" />
```

i am new into knockout and there is no much documentation on the their site to help,

Comment: Are your form submits hitting the action in your controller if you put a break point on the action?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update you binding on the input for the image/file

```
<input type="file" 
       class="form-control" 
       id="inputImagePath" 
       data-bind="fileSrc: ImagePath" 
       accept="image/*">
```

You can use custom binding handler to manage file data that will be sent to controller

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fileSrc = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                value(e.target.result);
            }
            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
        });
    }
};
```

Given that I don't know how your routes are configured, I believe that according to the name of your action `PostEmployee`, if you configured your API routing to use the default convention based routing then that action would map to `api/employees/PostEmployee`.

Your knockout code is trying to post to...

```
var employeeUrl = "http://localhost:50081/api/employees";
```

You can either change your url for the post to match action name or edit your controller action to follow the default convention...

```
public class EmployeesController: ApiController {

    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(EmployeeDetailVm))]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(EmployeeDetailVm employees){...}

}
```

Comment: thanks, i just tried your code now , but i got different error this time in my browser console saying POST http://localhost:50081/api/employees 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Are you able to debug the controller? Is the controller getting hit/called?

Comment: nope, can you give me an example how to structure the web api post controller,

Comment: How are you mapping your routes?

Comment: @MacdonaldAkoh I create a project using the information provided with my answer and was able to get the viewmodel posted to controller with all fields populated, including the image. Where are you getting the internal server error?

Comment: did you use exactly my api post controller?

Comment: this is the error am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: if you won't mind can you please send me your sample code , and how did you configure the API routing

Comment: i think i found out the error ExceptionMessage
:
"Value cannot be null.
↵Parameter name: input" got any ideal how to solve it?

Comment: Not at my PC at the moment. Will msg u as soon as I get back

Comment: How do i transfer to chat from here so I can help you quickly

Comment: About sending it in zip format to diomacdonald@gmail.com, will be highly appreciated